# O que é um campo "0" no SELECT do SQL?

Tags: sql, query, select

Não compreendi a utilização do `0` neste código:

```
SELECT substring ... 0 AS PARCELADO, ...
FROM ...
```

O que ele faz?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você não colocou o código todo, por isto pode ser algo diferente do que parece.

Ao contrário do que muitos imaginam o `SELECT` pode selecionar qualquer informação válida no SQL. Então o `0` é uma informação válida, é um literal numérico.

## Valor *dummy* facilitando a criação de código em tempo de execução

É comum usar o 0 no início ou no fim quando a *query* está sendo construída pela aplicação aos poucos. Quando você monta a lista de campos a serem selecionados para controlar se deve ter vírgula ou não fica um pouco mais complicado, então é simulado um campo extra para garantir a linearização do código.

Pode ser assim (em pseudocódigo):

```
query = "SELECT 0"
query += ", " + campo1
query += ", " + campo2
```

Ou também:

```
query = "SELECT "
query += campo1 + ", "
query += campo2 + ", "
query += "0"
```

Desta forma a vírgula não fica "solta".

## Mantendo ordem natural dos dados

Também pode ser usado para que nenhuma ordem específica seja usada. Uma forma de você anular alguma ordem usada por causa das demais cláusulas é usar isto para indicar que explicitamente algo que torne todos elementos iguais para fins de comparação da ordenação:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT 0)
```

## Ajudar no entendimento da *query*

Quando dados veem de fontes diferentes você pode querer saber qual parte da *query* resultou aquela linha, então usa uma coluna apenas para identificação:

```
SELECT 0, nome, ... FROM cliente WHERE id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, nome, ... FROM cliente WHERE id = 456
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/UnionAll.sql).

## Coluna virtual

É possível que sua aplicação precise de uma coluna virtual (algumas vezes chamada de coluna calculada). Ou seja, apesar da sua tabela não ter aquela coluna, uma *query* específica precisa desta coluna por alguma razão.

Como dito antes, o `SELECT` pode pegar qualquer expressão e não apenas os campos da tabela. Estas expressões podem ser úteis para cálculos ou outras manipulações que a aplicação precise processar.

Como neste caso não há nenhum cálculo ou variação do dado é provável que esta informação será preenchida de alguma forma pela aplicação e será usada por ela ou servirá para alguma decisão no momento que o dado retornar para escrita no banco de dados.

A resposta do Caputo dá mais detalhes sobre esta possibilidade.

Comment: Essa pergunta não está muito boa de ser respondida. Poderia ser ainda o 0 do isNull

Answer (score 13):

O uso de constantes em SQL preve que o resultado do campo seja sempre igual a constante.

Neste caso,

```
0 AS parcelado
```

Está trazendo todos os campos parcelado como 0. Supondo que existam 4 registros

```
| CampoA  |  CampoB  |
|    1    |  José    |
|    2    |  João    |
|    3    |  Pedro   |
```

Se eu fizer

```
SELECT
  CampoA,
  CampoB,
  0 AS Parcelado
FROM
  Minha Tabela
```

Eu teria como resultado

```
| CampoA  |  CampoB  | Parcelado |
|    1    |  José    |     0     |
|    2    |  João    |     0     |
|    3    |  Pedro   |     0     |
```

### Tudo bem, entendi. Mas para que isso?

Isto pode ser usado como artifício para:

1. Preencher este campo em RunTime via codigo
2. Trazer um campo esperado por código legado
3. Atender a um modelo de dados, onde este campo não seria necessário
4. Ter um campo para ser checked ou unchecked na interface

Comment: Um tempo atrás aqui no site eu vi um caso com `0 WHERE` (ou alguma coisa do tipo). É a mesma coisa?

Comment: Acho que o `0 WHERE` pode entrar também no caso que o @bigown citou. Aqui na empresa por exemplo, para obter metadados utilizam `WHERE 1 = 2` visto que um nunca será igual a 2